# How to use WL.Logger api to output log messages to a file

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an iOS app using IBM Worklight framework. I want to log messages as my code runs e.g. "application startup successful!"

My question is

How can I use WL.Logger api  to log messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Worklight 6.0:**

Take a look at the updated WL.Logger functionality inside IBM InfoCenter ([here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/c_configuring_logger.html) and [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_logger_methods.html)). Specifically the part that allows you to [set a callback](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_callback.html).

Open initOptions.js and add create a callback function that will be called after every log message is sent to the console:

```
var logHandler = function (message, priority, pkg) {
    //... write to a file or send logs to a server
};
```

You can use the [Cordova File API](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File) to write log messages to a file on the device (or JSONStore, LocalStorage, Cordova Storage, etc.). Later ([setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)) you could read the contents of that file and send it to a server using an adapter (or [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), etc.). On the server you could [use Java inside Adapters](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/04_08_Using_Java_in_adapters.pdf) to [write to files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2885224/186909)... or write to a DB, [ElasticSearch Cluster](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), [data infrastructure cloud offering](http://www.treasure-data.com/), etc.

```
var wlInitOptions = {

    connectOnStartup : true,

    logger : {enabled: true, level: 'debug', stringify: true, pretty: false,
        tag: {level: false, pkg: true}, whitelist: [], blacklist: [], callback: logHandler}

};
```

Notice `callback: logHandler` in the code block above.

**Worklight pre-6.0:**

This functionality is not part of WL.Logger on Worklight pre 6.0, but you could implement it. For example:

```
//Implementation:
var LoggerWrapper = (function (callback) {

    var _cb, _ctx;

    return {

        setCallbackAndContext : function (cb, ctx) {
            _cb = cb;
            _ctx = ctx;
        }

        log : function () {
            console.log.apply(console, arguments);
            _cb(_ctx, arguments)

        }
    }

})();

//Usage:
LoggerWrapper.setCallbackAndContext(functionThatCallsAdapter, ObjectThatHasNetworkEnvironmentInfoEtc);

LoggerWrapper.log('hello');
```

**APIs that provide useful info. (context) that could be appended to log messages:**

```
environment : WL.Client.getAppProperty(WL.AppProp.ENVIRONMENT)
appName : WL.Client.getAppProperty(WL.AppProp.APP_DISPLAY_NAME)
appVersion : WL.Client.getAppProperty(WL.AppProp.APP_VERSION)
deviceContext : WL.Device.getContext() //see Location Services API
network: WL.Device.getNetworkInfo() //async
timestamp: new Date()
```

**Debug Mode**

A lot of apps capture extra logs and send them to the server by enabling a 'debug mode', not by default.

[image: debug mode example]

**Operational Analytics**

If you have configured the new [Operational Analytics feature](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/monitor/c_operational_analytics.html) you can simply call [WL.Analytics.log](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_analytics_log.html) in the callback (`logHandler`). Pass the the log messages and they will show up in the [Analytics Search View](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/monitor/c_analytics_search.html).