# IBM Worklight 6.1 write client side logs to messages.log

Tags: javascript, logging, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

In our application we managed to write client-side logs to server by using `WL.Client.logActivity`. Is there a way to write these logs to messages.log file of the server and not to wlreport database? i've read some related posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20941874/ibm-worklight-6-0-how-to-write-logs-to-a-file-and-send-them-back) but we dont want to have a custom log file submited by the user.

So can we send somehow client-side logs back to server's  messages.log?

Comment: messages.log is not meant for client-side logs. You should probably not scew the purpose of tools and instead use tools designated to their uses. Have you tried using Worklight analytics instead?

Comment: I meant to write "skew" not "scew", in case that was not clear.

Comment: Yes you were right.. i use the WL.Client.logActivity instead.thanks

Comment: Could you write the correct answer please?

Answer (score 1):

Just launching an idea: Why don't you create an adapter that exposes a method "log", then when you want to log something from the client in the server side, you may do:

WL.Client.invokeProcedure(
{
    adapter : 'adapter-name',
    procedure : 'log',
    parameters : ['your_message']
}
);

And, on the adapter's log implementation, you could use WL.Logger.x API to write to the internal log files (I'm 100% sure, but I think that will write to messages.log)